# How to update two tables without receiving the ambiguous error message

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am looking to be able to edit the information in the two tables but I keep receiving the fname ambiguous error message?

```
$query = "UPDATE `test2`, `test3`  SET `fname`='$name', `stdate`='$stdate',`endate`='$endate',`addr1`='$addr1',`addr2`='$addr2',`city`='$city',`state`='$state',`zip`='$zip',`description`='$desc',`name`='$fileName',`size`='$fileSize',`type`='$fileType',`content`=' ',`link`='$link',`user`='$user' WHERE `id`='$id'";
}}}
else {   
$query = "UPDATE `test2`, `test3` SET `fname`='$name', `stdate`='$stdate',`endate`='$endate',`addr1`='$addr1',`addr2`='$addr2',`city`='$city',`state`='$state',`zip`='$zip',`description`='$desc',`name`=' ',`size`='0',`type`=' ',`content`=' ',`link`='$link',`user`='$user' WHERE `id`='$id'";
}
```

Comment: ... can you post this error message? It is likely not ambiguous to others.

Comment: use `table_name.field_name` to end the confusion ..`test2.fname=`..

Comment: @JacobPollack I think he meant the error that specifically relates to "ambiguous column names"

Comment: @Dagon this is there error message i get now errorError, query failed. Unknown column 'test2.fname' in 'field list'

Comment: then `test2.fname` does not exist

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can either use table aliases or prefix every field of a given table with its table name and a dot (as mentioned by @Dagon):

```
table_name.field_name
```

Comment: this is there error message i get now errorError, query failed. Unknown column 'test2.fname' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Qualify all column names with table name, or table alias. e.g.

```
UPDATE `test2` t2
 CROSS
  JOIN `test3` t3
   SET t2.fname = ... 
     , t3.stdate = ...
 WHERE t2.id = ...
```

(I included the CROSS keywork because I don't see any join predicates in your statement. Maybe that reference to `id` was meant to reference both t2.id and t3.id, or there's a foreign key?

```
UPDATE `test2` t2
  JOIN `test3` t3
    ON t2.id = t3.t2_id 
   SET t2.fname = ... 
     , t3.stdate = ...
 WHERE t2.id = ...
```